# How to access a cell that is generated in a GridPane?

Tags: javafx

I need to add a shape into a specific cell (middle centered one) in my GridPane.

This is how cells (StackPane) are made in my GridPane:

```
private StackPane createCell() {
    StackPane cell = new StackPane();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("cell");
    return cell;
}
```

I have tried to get the centered cell with this piece of method:

```
private Node getCenteredNodeGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
    for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
        if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col/2 && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row/2) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then, get the node:

```
Node centeredNode = getCenteredNodeGridPane(grid, 20, 20);
centeredNode ...... ??????
```

But i have no access to the actual StackPane of this node.
I need something like,

> centeredNode.getChildren().add(shape);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only add `StackPane`s as child nodes of the grid pane, you just need to cast the result:

```
StackPane centeredNode = (StackPane) getCenteredNodeGridPane(grid, 20, 20);
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you could of course do this in your `getCenteredNodeGridPane` method, and add type checking:

```
private StackPane getCenteredNodeGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
    for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
        if (node instanceof StackPane 
         && GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col/2 
         && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row/2) {
            return (StackPane) node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Amazing as usual James. My respect :)